# Edit label in wordpress frond-end admin bar

Tags: wordpress

I would like to edit the text of a label in the WordPress admin bar.

```
function customize_my_wp_admin_bar(){
    global $wp_admin_bar;

    $title = $wp_admin_bar->get_node('vc_inline-admin-bar-link')->title;
    $title = 'edit in website';
}

add_action( 'wp_before_admin_bar_render', 'customize_my_wp_admin_bar' );
```

Answer (score -1):

With this tech, you might solve your problem.

First: You must write callback function to wp-includes/admin-bar.php like this.

```
function wp_admin_bar_custom( $wp_admin_bar )
{
    $newtitle = __('Custom Title', 'cuar');
    $wp_admin_bar->add_node( array( 'id' => 'customer-area', 'title' => $newtitle, ) );
}
```

Next: You should insert this code to wp-includes/class-wp-admin-bar.php
Find add_menus function and rewrite that function.
You can add `add_action( 'admin_bar_menu', 'wp_admin_bar_custom', 201);` above `do_action( 'add_admin_bar_menus' );`.

Following these step, you can see 'Custom Title' in your WP's admin-bar.

Comment: Warning: never edit Wordpress core files.